# Alog conversion to Java

Tags: java, android, objective-c, eclipse

How can I convert use this code in Android or Java since it's written in Objective C?

```
ALog(@"ERROR: Account with UserId:%@ AccountType:%d AccoundId:%d DOES NOT EXIST!",
     account.userId, account.accountType, account.accountId);
```

Comment: Would Log4j be part of the answer?

Comment: Probably. http://code.google.com/p/android-logging-log4j/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for Android you'll want to do something like the following:

```
Log.i("AccountActivity", "Account with UserId: " + userId +
      " AccountType: " + accountType +
      " AccountId: " + accountId +
      " Does not exist.");
```

That would appear in logcat formatted by the activity and level (info, in this case).  Might look like this:

```
I/AccountActivity( 1234): Account with UserId: {id} AccountType: {type} AccountId: {id} Does not exist.
```

Not sure if this answers your question... take a look here for further help: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-log.html

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at MessageFormat class:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html

And some logging framework, like  log4j, commons-logging or whatever you find most convenient